# PHP line break Showing <br/> tag in echo

Tags: php, line-breaks

I want to break the new lines of texarea input and needs to show that as next line in frond end.

I tried all the below methods..

```
preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>', Input::get('post_content'));
str_replace('<br />', "\n", Input::get('post_content'));
```

After inserting data to table, the **preg_replace** function inserting 
 tag in all line breaks.

But when I echo the table column its showing the 
 tag as like a string.

ScrrenShot..

[image]

How to fix this issue.. ?

Comment: there is a php function `nl2br()`. use `nl2br(Input::get('post_content')))`

Comment: While inserting to db or echo from db ?

Comment: let me check. 1 sec. so that not required in echo statement right ?

Comment: yes, you can simply echo the retrieve string and you saw the break lines....

Comment: Its showing the <br/> tag in my output.. not breaking line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111329/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-jpdevs).

Comment: Your database field must have the type => `text` and collation => `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Because my answer is not a feasible answer so i delete the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the `Input::get('post_content')` part of the code, this is Laravel framework. If you're also using Blade template, you can print your variable unescaped like this: `{!! $content !!}`

Comment: Dude,  yes Its laravel. let me check the solution.

Comment: how can i show this in textarea field also.In backend I need to give a edit ssection and show this as line break ?

Comment: You should save it into your database *before* converting new lines to `<br>`s.

Comment: How ? {!! str_replace("<br />", "\n",$data->post_content)!!} ?

Comment: No, you should save the `Input::get('post_content')` directly into the database, and edit that data. You only convert `\n`s to `<br>`s when you display it on the screen.